# How to read file capabilities using Python?

Tags: python, linux, linux-capabilities

On Linux systems root privileges can be granted more selectively than adding the setuid bit using file capabilities. See [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) for details. These are attributes of files and can be read using the `getcap` program. How can these attributes be retrieved in Python?

Even though running the `getcap` program using e.g. `subprocess` for answering such a question is possible it is not desirable when retrieving very many capabilities.

It should be possible to devise a solution using `ctypes`. Are there alternatives to this approach or even libraries facilitating this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 3.3 comes with `os.getxattr`. If not, yeah... one way would be using `ctypes`, at least to get the raw stuff, or maybe use [`pyxattr`](http://pyxattr.k1024.org/module.html)

For `pyxattr`:

```
>>> import xattr
>>> xattr.listxattr("/bin/ping")
(u'security.capability',)
>>> xattr.getxattr("/bin/ping", "security.capability")
'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

For Python 3.3's version, it's essentially the same, just importing `os`, instead of `xattr`. `ctypes` is a bit more involved, though.

Now, we're getting the raw result, meaning that those two are most useful only retrieving textual attributes. But... we can use the same approach of `getcap`, through `libcap` itself [warning, this will work as-is only on Python 2, as written originally - read the note at the end for details]:

```
import ctypes

libcap = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libcap.so")
cap_t = libcap.cap_get_file('/bin/ping')
libcap.cap_to_text.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
libcap.cap_to_text(cap_t, None)
```

which gives me:

```
'= cap_net_raw+p'
```

probably more useful for you.

**PS**: note that `cap_to_text` returns a `malloc`ed string. It's your job to deallocate it using `cap_free`

Hint about the "binary gibberish":

```
>>> import struct
>>> caps = '\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack("<IIIII", caps)
(33554432, 8192, 0, 0, 0)
```

In that `8192`, the only active bit is the 13th. If you go to `linux/capability.h`, you'll see that `CAP_NET_RAW` is defined at `13`.

Now, if you want to write a module with all those constants, you can decode the info. But I'd say it's much more laborious than just using `ctypes` + `libcap`.

PS2: I notice another answer mentioning that there are problems with my invocation on the `ctype` solution. That's because I *likely* wrote that using Python 2.x back then in 2014 (as Python 3 offered `os.getxattr`).

The key here is reminding that back in Python 2.x there were no `bytes` objects, and `str` and `unicode` where separate entities. Python 3.x merged those two so that `str` is now basically `unicode`, and that may mess up with the C interface.

So, if using Python 3 (likely the case at this point), make sure to turn your strings into `bytes` (e.g., `foo_bar.encode('utf-8')`) before passing them to `libcap`, and the reverse operation with the results.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example? E.g. evaluating the capabilities of `/bin/ping`?

Comment: Depends on which one you want to use... `pyxattr` comes with examples in the documentation.

Comment: All of them? ;-) I can upvote multiple answers. Just make sure that the result is human readable.

Comment: Btw, `xtattr`'s documentation insists that `getxattr` is deprecated in favour of `get`, and so on, from version 0.4... but I installed version 0.7.3 and they're not there...

Comment: The `pyxattr` based solution is useless, because all you get is binary gibberish. The `ctypes` solution is laborious, but gives a useful result, hence the upvote.

Comment: It's not binary gibberish. It's a struct with data that you can decode using the `#defines` in `capability.h`. I'm afraid I'm not going to do that work for you.

Comment: Make sure to use `struct.unpack("<IIIII", caps)`, or it will fail horribly on big-endian architectures.

Comment: I love the solution that uses libcap, could you also write an example of setcap?

Comment: @Zibri uh... it's been a loooong time since I wrote this and I'd have to look it up. Plus, it's out of the scope of the question. Would you post a separate one? You can reference this answer (if you link the new question here as well I'll try to answer if I have the time)

Comment: Nevermind.. I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77609944/236062

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code from Ricardo Cárdenes's answer, but it did not work properly for me, because some details of the `ctypes` invocation incorrect. This issue caused a truncated path string to be passed to `getxattr(...)` inside of `libcap`, which thus returned the wrong capabilities list for the wrong item (the `/` directory, or other first path character, and not the actual path).

It is very important to remember and account for the difference between `str` and `bytes` in Python 3.X. This code works properly on Python 3.5/3.6:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes
import os
import sys

# load shared library
libcap = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libcap.so')

class libcap_auto_c_char_p(ctypes.c_char_p):
    def __del__(self):
        libcap.cap_free(self)

# cap_t cap_get_file(const char *path_p)
libcap.cap_get_file.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
libcap.cap_get_file.restype  = ctypes.c_void_p

# char* cap_to_text(cap_t caps, ssize_t *length_p)
libcap.cap_to_text.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
libcap.cap_to_text.restype  = libcap_auto_c_char_p

def cap_get_file(path):
    cap_t = libcap.cap_get_file(path.encode('utf-8'))
    if cap_t is None:
        return ''
    else:
        return libcap.cap_to_text(cap_t, None).value.decode('utf-8')

print(cap_get_file('/usr/bin/traceroute6.iputils'))
print(cap_get_file('/usr/bin/systemd-detect-virt'))
print(cap_get_file('/usr/bin/mtr'))
print(cap_get_file('/usr/bin/tar'))
print(cap_get_file('/usr/bin/bogus'))
```

The output will look like this (anything nonexistent, or with no capabilities set just returns `''`:

```
= cap_net_raw+ep
= cap_dac_override,cap_sys_ptrace+ep
= cap_net_raw+ep
```

Answer (score 0):

getcap.py

```
import ctypes, sys, glob

libcap = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(glob.glob("/lib/libcap*")[0])
cap_t = libcap.cap_get_file(sys.argv[1])
libcap.cap_to_text.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
print libcap.cap_to_text(cap_t, None)
```

setcap.py  (set all capabilities =ep)

```
import ctypes, sys, glob

libcap = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(glob.glob("/lib/libcap*")[0])

libcap.cap_from_text.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
libcap.cap_from_text.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
libcap.cap_set_file.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_void_p]

cap = '=ep'
path = sys.argv[1]
print(path)
cap_t = libcap.cap_from_text(cap)
status = libcap.cap_set_file(path,cap_t)

if(status == 0):
    print (cap + " was successfully added to " + path)
```

Notes:

- I search for the library because on some systems the library name
  changes.
- Setcap sets all capabilies. You can change the code or
  add an argv to add any capability.